# How to do division of cells in a csv file before importing into postgres using a python script?

Tags: python, postgresql, csv

I want to insert price of a product by doing sales dollars/sales units (or 0 if sales unit is 0) into a postgres sql. Is there I can do this when inserting into the database or do I have to run an update? (see below)

```
arg = {
            'sales_dollars': row[8].strip()
            'sales_units': row[9].strip()
            'average_on_hand_dollars': row[11].strip()
            'average_on_hand': row[12].strip() }

cur.execute(
            """INSERT INTO 
            "Sales_Inventory"("sales_dollars","sales_units", "price", "average_on_hand_dollars","average_on_hand", "cost")
             select
                %(sales_dollars)s,
                %(sales_units)s,
                #price = sales_dolars/sales_unit should go here
                %(average_on_hand_dollars)s,
                %(average_on_hand)s
                #cost = average_on_hand_dollars/average_on_hand should go here
            ;""", arg)
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Consider using COPY statement. It 'moves data between PostgreSQL tables and standard file-system files'. See:
postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add another key-value pair:

```
arg['price'] = arg['sales_dollars']/arg['sales_units']

cur.execute( # ...
                %(price)s
             # ...
```

Of course your values are strings, not numbers, so that `/` isn't going to do you much good. But that's easy to fix: convert to numbers, divide, then optionally convert back to string:

```
arg['price'] = float(arg['sales_dollars'])/float(arg['sales_units'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that would be:

```
if not arg["sales_dollars"]:
   arg["sales_dollars"] == 0
```

... in your python.  If for some reason that's infeasible, PostgreSQL can deal with this via COALESCE:

```
COALESCE(%{sales_dollars}s, 0)
```

... which can be inserted where you'd put a field.